# Replace NaN values of pandas.DataFrame with values from list

Tags: python, pandas

In a python script using the library `pandas`, I have a dataset of let's say 100 lines with a feature "X", containing 36 `NaN` values, and a list of size 36.

I want to replace all the 36 missing values of the column "X" by the 36 values I have in my list.

It's likely to be a dumb question, but I went through all the doc and couldn't find a way to do it.

Here's an example :

**INPUT**

```
Data:   X      Y
        1      8
        2      3
        NaN    2
        NaN    7
        1      2
        NaN    2
```

**Filler**

```
List: [8, 6, 3]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Data:   X      Y
        1      8
        2      3
        8      2
        6      7
        1      2
        3      2
```

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output

Comment: Sure, I edited my post to add it.

Comment: Are all the `NaN` values in the same column? How do you replace the `NaN` values with your list? Do you just do that sequentially, i.e. replace the first `NaN` value with the fist value in the list, and so on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with your dataframe `df`

```
print(df)

     X  Y
0  1.0  8
1  2.0  3
2  NaN  2
3  NaN  7
4  1.0  2
5  NaN  2
```

Define the values you want to fill with (Note: there must be the same number of elements in your `filler` list as `NaN` values in your dataframe)

```
filler = [8, 6, 3]
```

Filter your column (that contains the `NaN` values) and overwrite the selected rows with your `filler`

<strike>`df.X[df.X.isnull()] = filler`</strike>

```
df.loc[df.X.isnull(), 'X'] = filler
```

which gives:

```
print(df)

     X  Y
0  1.0  8
1  2.0  3
2  8.0  2
3  6.0  7
4  1.0  2
5  3.0  2
```

Comment: It works just fine, thanks, but I've got a warning "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". It's weird as I see that it indeed modifies `df`...

Comment: According to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) listed in the warning, you need to change `df.X[df.X.isnull()]` to `df.loc[df.X.isnull(), 'X']`

Comment: @MadPhysicist is right if you want to avoid this warning.  Personally I tend to use the original syntax since it looks more intuitive (to me) and I just ignore the warnings since it does exactly what I want anyway.  But if the `.loc` method looks good to you then you should definitely use that one instead.

Comment: The warning is not a random occurrence. It happens because the indexed column may in fact be a copy, in which case the assignment will not actually modify the original data frame. You have been lucky thus far in that you have been getting views instead of copies, but that does not make it a good habit.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're totally right. I shouldn't be demonstrating a method for solving a problem that is unstable, especially when helping others. I will edit the answer and I promise not to pass on my bad practices in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the efficient one, but still works :)
First find all index for the Nan's and replace them in loop. Assuming that list is always bigger than number of Nan's

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 1, 2], 'B': [10, np.nan, np.nan], 'C': [[20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25], np.nan]})
lst=[12,35,78]

index = df['B'].index[df['B'].apply(np.isnan)] #find Index
cnt=0
for item in index:
    df.set_value(item, 'B', lst[item]) #replace Nan of the nth index with value from Nth value from list
    cnt=cnt+1

print df

     A     B             C
0  NaN  10.0  [20, 21, 22]
1  1.0   NaN  [23, 24, 25]
2  2.0   NaN           NaN
```

Output .

```
     A     B             C
0  NaN  10.0  [20, 21, 22]
1  1.0  35.0  [23, 24, 25]
2  2.0  78.0           NaN
```

Comment: Here it would replace the 10 of the first row, I don't want to do it : I just want to change the NaN values.

Comment: It wont , only replaces Nan's

Comment: Ok if index corresponds to the missing lines, you're right sry

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use an iterator as an index marker for replacing your NaN's with the value in your custom list:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

your_df = pd.DataFrame({'your_column': [0,1,2,np.nan,4,6,np.nan,np.nan,7,8,np.nan,9]})  # a df with 4 NaN's
print your_df

your_custom_list = [1,3,6,8]  # custom list with 4 fillers

your_column_vals = your_df['your_column'].values

i_custom = 0  # starting index on your iterator for your custom list
for i in range(len(your_column_vals)):
    if np.isnan(your_column_vals[i]):
        your_column_vals[i] = your_custom_list[i_custom]
        i_custom += 1  # increase the index

your_df['your_column'] = your_column_vals

print your_df
```

Output:

```
    your_column
0           0.0
1           1.0
2           2.0
3           NaN
4           4.0
5           6.0
6           NaN
7           NaN
8           7.0
9           8.0
10          NaN
11          9.0
    your_column
0           0.0
1           1.0
2           2.0
3           1.0
4           4.0
5           6.0
6           3.0
7           6.0
8           7.0
9           8.0
10          8.0
11          9.0
```