# Fill DataFrame NaN with another DataFrame with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am sure this has been answered before but I cannot seem to find the right solution. I have tried pd.merge, merge, combine_first and update and they all don't seem to get the right job. They either create a new variable with an _x or they imply stack in below. I am wishing to merge `df1` into `df` where column `c` is missing values. I wish to do this for each `id` on each `date`

Example `df` for task

**df**

```
  date     id    a    b   c     d
1/1/2000    1   10   20   10   11
1/1/2000    2   11   21   NaN  11
1/1/2000    3   15   20   NaN  11
1/1/2000    4   12   24   13   11
1/2/2000    1   10   25   10   11
1/2/2000    2   10   20   NaN  15
1/2/2000    3   10   26   NaN  11
1/2/2000    4   10   20   16   13
1/3/2000    1   10   20   10   11
1/3/2000    2   10   20   NaN  11
1/3/2000    3   10   20   NaN  11
1/3/2000    4   10   20   10   11
```

**df1**

```
 date         id   c    
12/29/1999    2   1  
12/30/1999    3   1  
12/30/1999    2   1  
12/31/1999    3   1  
12/31/1999    2   1  
12/31/1999    4   1  
1/1/2000      2   1  
1/1/2000      3   14  
1/2/2000      2   13  
1/2/2000      3   22  
1/3/2000      2   13  
1/3/2000      3   18
```

**desired df after combining `df` and `d1`**

**df**

```
  date     id    a    b   c     d
1/1/2000    1   10   20   10   11
1/1/2000    2   11   21   1    11
1/1/2000    3   15   20   14   11
1/1/2000    4   12   24   13   11
1/2/2000    1   10   25   10   11
1/2/2000    2   10   20   13   15
1/2/2000    3   10   26   22   11
1/2/2000    4   10   20   16   13
1/3/2000    1   10   20   10   11
1/3/2000    2   10   20   13   11
1/3/2000    3   10   20   18   11
1/3/2000    4   10   20   10   11
```

Comment: It is date aswell. Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets create a `MultiIndex` in both the dataframe with `id` and `date` columns then use `Series.fillna` to fill the `NaN` values in column `c` of `df1` from corresponding values in `df2`:

```
df1['c'] = df1.set_index(['date', 'id'])['c']\
              .fillna(df2.set_index(['id', 'date'])['c']).tolist()
```

---

```
        date  id   a   b     c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10  20  10.0  11
1   1/1/2000   2  11  21   1.0  11
2   1/1/2000   3  15  20  14.0  11
3   1/1/2000   4  12  24  13.0  11
4   1/2/2000   1  10  25  10.0  11
5   1/2/2000   2  10  20  13.0  15
6   1/2/2000   3  10  26  22.0  11
7   1/2/2000   4  10  20  16.0  13
8   1/3/2000   1  10  20  10.0  11
9   1/3/2000   2  10  20  13.0  11
10  1/3/2000   3  10  20  18.0  11
11  1/3/2000   4  10  20  10.0  11
```

Comment: Thanks for your go. I have updated the question as `df1` and `df` have different lengths. When I follow the above, the column in `df` is still left empty

Comment: @oceanbeach96 I think this should work fine..Make sure you have replace `df1` with `df` and `df2` with `df1` in the code..

Answer (score 0):

At least in your example, you can [fill your NA values from a list of values (without indexing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167429/replace-nan-values-of-pandas-dataframe-with-values-from-list).  AKA, `df1`, is always the same length as the number of missing values:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[df['c'].isna(), 'c'] = list(df1['c'])
```

Result:

```
        date  id   a   b     c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10  20  10.0  11
1   1/1/2000   2  11  21   1.0  11
2   1/1/2000   3  15  20  14.0  11
3   1/1/2000   4  12  24  13.0  11
4   1/2/2000   1  10  25  10.0  11
5   1/2/2000   2  10  20  13.0  15
6   1/2/2000   3  10  26  22.0  11
7   1/2/2000   4  10  20  16.0  13
8   1/3/2000   1  10  20  10.0  11
9   1/3/2000   2  10  20  13.0  11
10  1/3/2000   3  10  20  18.0  11
11  1/3/2000   4  10  20  10.0  11
```

Comment: Thanks for your go. I have updated the question as `df1` and `df` have different lengths. When I follow the above, the column in `df` is still left empty